# TreeView.RowActivated not triggered by double click

Tags: c#, gtk#

```
1st try: Issue triggered after 46 double clicks
2nd try: Issue triggered after 41 double clicks
3rd try: Issue triggered after 59 double clicks

//------
private void TreeViewMYLISTRowActivated(object o, Gtk.RowActivateArts args){
     //do something
}
//------
```

TreeViewMYLISTRowActivated event is supposed to be triggered when user press ENTER on the highlighted row OR user double clicks on a row. But somehow the double-click sometimes fail to trigger the event

After triggering this issue, 'double-clicks' could never raise the Event-"row_activated" again. Unless I stop the program and debug it again. Then after several consecutive double-clicks, it triggers again

Comment: Can you please show some code? Else how are we supposed to help with it?

Comment: Is it okay to just show the flow of the code? I can't show it publicly since it is work related

Comment: Then try to make an example that we can run, we'll be able to help you then :)